# Entity Framework performance issue when retrieving sub entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have an entity that contains millions of sub-entities, structure like this:

```
public class Sample
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public string SampleNo { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<SampleCustomFieldValue> CustomFieldValues { get; set; }
}

public class SampleCustomFieldValue
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    //some attributes...        

    public virtual Sample ParentSample
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

when I call `sample.CustomFieldValues`, it will hang there forever. I can see the SQL is generated like this:

```
    SELECT 
       [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
       [Extent1].[ParentSample_ID] AS [ParentSample_ID]
    FROM [dbo].[SampleCustomFieldValues] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[ParentSample_ID] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[ParentSample_ID] = @EntityKeyValue1)
```

which will be executed only 1 or 2 secs to get all data in SQL Server Management Studio.

Could you please tell me what's happening here?

Comment: are you displaying the data into a Datagridview or something

Comment: Can you show your EF query ?

Comment: A very short query can take a very long time when many objects must be materialized. SSMS doesn't have to build CLR objects and it shows the *first* results in no time while maybe in the background it keeps streaming records to the output window. Somehow you have to reduce the number of records you grab from the database to a manageable amount.